# Why are there no trades occurring in the algorithm?

Tags: python

So I am trying to make a basic trading algorithm with the use of the ichimoku cloud. So far I have created the indicators, created buying conditions and selling conditions, though when I check the return it is 0, without any movement. This could because the strategy is not working well(which is fine I am not looking for it to be succseful, just for it to function), but I feel as though something in the code is wrong which is not letting it buy and sell. Supposedly, this strategy is supposed to buy when the price is above the cloud, and if the price is above the cloud and the conversion line crosses above the base line then that is a buy. Then a sell signal would be if the conversion line crosses above the price or the price falls bellow the cloud. 
the code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import matplotlib as mpl
from mplfinance.original_flavor import candlestick_ohlc
import matplotlib.dates as dates
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf
%matplotlib inline
style.use('ggplot')


#GETTING DATA
start = datetime.datetime(2017,1,25)
end = datetime.datetime(2020,1,5)
d = pdr.get_data_yahoo("SPY", start, end)


#CREATING INDICATORS
# the conversion line, also known as the Tenkan-sen
nine_period_high = d['High'].rolling(window=9).max()
nine_period_low = d['Low'].rolling(window=9).min()
d['Conversion_Line'] = (nine_period_high + nine_period_low)/2

#the base line, also known as the Kijun-Sen
twenty_six_period_high = d['High'].rolling(window=26).max()
twenty_six_period_low = d['Low'].rolling(window=26).min()
d['Base_Line'] = (twenty_six_period_high + twenty_six_period_low)/2


#Leading Span A, also known as the Senkou Span A
d['Leading_Span_A'] = ((d['Conversion_Line']+d['Base_Line'])/2).shift(26)

#Leading Span B, also known as the Senkou Span B
fifty_two_period_high = d['High'].rolling(window=52).max()
fifty_two_period_low = d['Low'].rolling(window=52).min()
d['Leading_Span_B'] = ((fifty_two_period_high+fifty_two_period_low)/2).shift(26)


#LONG INDICATORS FOR BUYING
#Is the price greater than the cloud
d.dropna(inplace=True)
d['above_cloud'] = 0
d['above_cloud']=np.where((d['Low'] > d['Leading_Span_A']) & 
                          (d['Low'] > d['Leading_Span_B']), 1, d['above_cloud'])
d['above_cloud']=np.where((d['High'] < d['Leading_Span_A']) & 
                          (d['High'] < d['Leading_Span_B']), -1, d['above_cloud'])


#Is the Fast MA, the conversion Line, Crossing above the Slow MA, Base Line
d['Conversion_Base_cross'] = np.NaN
d['Conversion_Base_cross'] = np.where((d['Conversion_Line'].shift(1) <= d['Base_Line'].shift(1)) & 
                                      (d['Conversion_Line'] > d['Base_Line']), 1, d['Conversion_Base_cross'])
d['Conversion_Base_cross'] = np.where((d['Conversion_Line'].shift(1) >= d['Base_Line'].shift(1)) & 
                                      (d['Conversion_Line'] < d['Base_Line']), -1, d['Conversion_Base_cross'])

#LONG INDICATORS FOR SELLING
#Is the Price Closing below the Conversion Line
x=np.NaN
d['Conversion_Price_Cross']= np.NaN
d['Conversion_Price_Cross'] = np.where((d['Open'].shift(1) >= d['Conversion_Line'].shift(1)) & 
                                       (d['Open'] < d['Conversion_Line']), -1, d['Conversion_Price_Cross'])
#BUYING
x=np.NaN
d['buy'] = np.NaN
d['buy']=np.where((d['above_cloud'].shift(1) == 1) & 
                  (d['Conversion_Base_cross'].shift(1) == 1), 1, d['buy'])
d['buy'].ffill(inplace=True)

#SELLING
x=np.NaN
d['sell'] = np.NaN
d['sell'] =np.where((d['Conversion_Price_Cross'].shift(1) == -1) |
                    (d['Conversion_Base_cross'].shift(1) == -1), -1, d['sell'])
d['sell'].ffill(inplace=True)
#RETURN
d['position'] = d['buy'] + d['sell']
d['stock_returns'] = np.log(d['Close']) - np.log(d['Close'].shift(1))
d['strategy_returns'] = d['stock_returns'] * d['position']
d[['stock_returns','strategy_returns']].cumsum().plot(figsize=(15,8))
```

Comment: So you want us to debug your code, and you don't even know that there's a bug?

Comment: @tom10, how would I go about doing that

Comment: In general you should test your code while you write it, building a few lines at a time, making sure they work as expect as you go along.  The task that you're presenting here, that is, start with 50 lines of code and try to figure out what's going on, is very difficult. If you find problems as you go along, you will be able to say, "here are two lines of code that don't do what I want" and people will be able to help.

Comment: Is there a **specific** issue? You cannot expect us to debug your entire program for you. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

I might have found it quite fast or "something more reasonable". Nevertheless, I also have to second the comments: this is a by far a too big *snippet*, it is/was just pure debugging work to do and reading/knowing the docs.

Quickly investigating the data, starting from the back:

```
d["position"] == [..., 0, ...]
```

is always zero, 652 items ... so obviously the "strategy_returns" are also `0` as `d['stock_returns']` is always multiplied with 0. Further, "position" is calculated as the sum of `buy` and `sell`:

```
d["position"] = d["buy"] + d["sell"]
```

looking into `buy` and `sell` it still makes sense:

- 664 items in `buy` and `sell`, both starting with `nan` items:

  - `buy == [12x nan, 652x 1.0]`
  - `sell == [3x nan, 661x -1.0]`
- `.sum()` indicates that both `buy` and `sell` only contain `1.0` or `-1.0` apart from `nan`

so far, just used the following expressions:

```
d["buy"].sum(), d["buy"].count() == 652.0 664
d["buy"])[:15] == [..., 12x nan, ..., 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]

d["sell"].sum(), d["sell"].count() == -661.0 664
d["sell"])[:15] == [..., 3x nan, ..., -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0]
```

I believe you should check the [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) docs. E.g., this `sell` calculation:

```
d['sell'] = np.where((d['Conversion_Price_Cross'].shift(1) == -1) |
                (d['Conversion_Base_cross'].shift(1) == -1), -1, d['sell'])
```

Essentially the docs say:

```
numpy.where(condition[, x, y])
    Return elements chosen from x or y depending on condition.
```

But you choose either `-1` or `d["sell"]`, my impression is that you would like to choose from either `-1 == sell` or `0 == do nothing`. At least changing both np.where() last arguments for d["sell"] and d["buy"] leave me with *something*:

```
axes[0].plot(d[['stock_returns','strategy_returns']].cumsum())
```

Shows at least some [up & down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5XqU.png). Nevertheless, nobody knows if this is right or not, especially for financial applications you really need extensive testing, which is far easier for more granular code.

As @tom10 says, defining the problem (inputs) and the expected outcome is crucial for getting help. Anything else does not allow anybody, like me now, to judge whether something is *fixed* or just *broken in another way*.

Comment: I do not know why this got downvoted, and I was the one who asked the question (I did not down vote it though because of my reputation I can not upvote your response). This was extremely helpful in solving the problem. So what I found out is that when I was saying 'buy' I ment 'long', and when I said 'sell', I ment short. So what I was doing was creating positions that cancled each other out. So what I had to do was add 'sell' and 'cover' conditions respectively, which solved the problem.